# Open subsets of $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

Denote $I=[0,1]$ and endow $I$ with the subspace topology as a subset of $\mathbb R$. Then the only open subsets of $I$ are of the form:

1. $(a,b)$ with $0\le a\le 1$ and $0\le b \le 1$ and $a<b$.
2. $(a,1]$ with $0\le a<1$
3. $[0,b)$ with $0<b\le 1$.

Is this correct?

Edit : I meant the basic open sets.

Comment: No. $[0,\frac 1 3) \cup (\frac 1  2, \frac  3 4)$ is also open.

Comment: The open sets of $I$ are exactly those which can be written as $U\cap I$ for some open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes of course the union of open sets are open and the finite inetersection of open sets is still open.

Comment: These types of sets are already closed under finite intersections, so you don't get new sets that way.

Comment: How do you define "basic"?

Comment: @palio $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ is not a basic open set if one chooses some other basis for the topology.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the *basic* open sets. All open sets are unions of these, so also $(\frac12,\frac34) \cup (\frac78,1]$ is open etc.
But in many proofs it suffices to only consider basic open sets.

Comment: yes I meant the basic open sets. Thanks!

Comment: @palio: It would be better to say that these sets are **a** base for the subspaces topology. They are the usual base and the one with which it is generally easiest to work, but the topology has many other bases. For instance, the family of all sets that are the union of two disjoint members of your base is also a base for the subspace topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott it’s the default base for the order topology on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Of course: that’s why I called it the usual one. But it is at least misleading (and I would say simply wrong) to call it **the** base for that topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It does seem like the OP had the order topology in mind.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Quite likely, at least in the sense that the usual topology happens to be the order topology. (The general notion of the order topology may well not have been introduced.) But that has no bearing on what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

To tell that a open set is a basic open set makes no sense unless you previously specify a basis.

The question you are asking should say "Is this family of open sets a basis for the topology?"

The answer is "yes".

Notice that is **a** basis.